# I2C communication Receiving NAK bit

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, atmega32

I've SAME51N19 controller, I'm using sercom 1 for I2C communication from PIN A16=PAD0 SDA & A17=PAD1 SCL.
[SAME51N19](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM_D5x_E5x_Family_Data_Sheet_DS60001507G.pdf) facing Issues while transferring the data on **address 0b0101001=0x29**. Also, checking on oscilloscope not getting good. Attaching the oscilloscope image. I'm using I2C on standard mode. As master generates the clock and slave use the same, I think we don't need to set clock as slave or in slave controller. **DefaultSharedI2CClockFrequency = 400000;** Please help me to solve the issue.
Checked the connections SDA-SDA & SCL-SCL
[image: oscilloscope screen shot]

Comment: Standard mode is 100kHz, not 400kHz.  Also, your scope trace looks quite aliased.  Are you able to turn the timebase down (sampling rate up) and measure the frequency?

Comment: yes. I can do that. Can be this issue is causing due to pulses are not reaching enough voltage for pulse 1? I've set channels on 5V. You can see some of the pulses from channel 2 is just reaching upto 3V?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by correcting the Transfer functions in code. It was just coding error. Thank you.

Comment: Can you shed a light and hence make this A meaningful? I.e. at least showing code before and after the changes you have done.